# Find a particular tag in html inspector

Tags: html, web-inspector

I need to locate all the h1 and h2 tags in a page. I could do this by searching through the code but the issue is that there are multiple includes and many pages, so i'll need to search through many pages.

Is there a way to search for a tag in the browser inspector.

Is there a search function for the web inspector?

Thanks

Comment: What are you searching for them for? You could run the text files through a quick script if you're just trying to search and replace. 

However, chrome does have a search function on the web inspector. It's at the very bottom left, you'll probably have to drag it up to make it a little bigger.

Comment: Basically just to see what tags are present so I can understand the current structure, for SEO and other reasons. Thanks for your reply. I'll check out the Web inspector search function.